# How to Ethereum wallet address generated by derived ECDSA Public key in Android

Tags: android, ethereum, ecdsa

I'm new to Ethereum and for learning purposes,How to Ethereum wallet address generated by derived ECDSA Public key in Android .

Comment: This has been answered before.
Link: [how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated)